# Why is strpos() not working when searching this .txt file?

Tags: php

So I am trying to collect and store emails addresses in a text file and is is working other than it not recognising if an address has already been submitted. It will add an address to the text file even if it is already present. Thank you for your insight.

```
<?php
function showForm() {
    echo '
    <form method="post" action="">
    Email Address: <input type="email" name="email"> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    ';
}

if(empty($_POST['submit']) === false) {
    $email = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['email']));

    $logname = 'email.txt';
    $logcontents = file_get_contents($logname);
$pos = strpos($logcontents, $email);

if ($pos === true) {
        die('You are already subscribed.');
    } else {
        $filecontents = $email.',';
        $fileopen = fopen($logname,'a+');
        $filewrite = fwrite($fileopen,$filecontents);
        $fileclose = fclose($fileopen);
        if(!$fileopen or !$filewrite or !$fileclose) {
            die('Error occured');
        } else {
            echo 'Your email has been added.';
        }
    }   
} else {
    showForm();
}

?>
```

Comment: email.txt contains ?

Comment: `$pos` will either be `false` or an integer value. it will not return the boolean true. Your `if` specifically and strictly checks that $pos is a boolean value of true, which it will never be.

Answer (score 3):

`strpos()` returns the position at which the string has been found, or `false`.

Checking `$pos === true` can never succeed because the return value of `strpos()` cannot be `true`.

Try `if ($pos !== false) { ...` instead.

Comment: ah yes! silly mistake thank you all. This worked a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Your this line:

```
$pos = strpos($logcontents, $email);
```

returns position of the string found, not boolean value.

AND

```
if ($pos === true) {
```

may contain `0` as position.

You should change this to:

```
if ($pos != false) {
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 0):

[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) won't ever return true. It can return position zero which will be interpreted by PHP as false unless you use strict comparison.

```
if ($pos !== false)
```